# Check if .ISO is already mounted in powershell, if not then mount

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I have an ISO file that I copied off of an old game disk. But in order for me to play the game, I have to mount the ISO. 
I wrote a small Batch file that runs the `.ps1` PowerShell file to mount the ISO and then runs the EXE to start the game after it has been mounted. My problem is, if I run the script more than once it will mount the ISO again.

I want to check if the ISO is attached, mount it if it is not, or run the EXE if it is.

Here's what I have to mount the ISO: 
Batch.

```
ECHO "Mounting Stunt Track Driver"

@ECHO off

Powershell.exe -executionpolicy remotesigned 
-File  "C:\Users\Allen\Documents\Games\Hot Wheels Stunt Track 
Driver\setup\hot98\mount.ps1"

start /d "C:\Users\Allen\Documents\Games\Hot Wheels Stunt Track 
Driver\setup\hot98" stunt.exe
```

PowerShell

```
#mounts the image
Mount-DiskImage -ImagePath "C:\Users\Allen\Documents\Games\Hot Wheels Stunt 
Track Driver\setup\hot98\HotwheelsStuntTrack.iso"
```

Answer (score 5):

this snippet will only mount image if it's not mounted :

```
if(!(get-DiskImage -ImagePath C:\testshare\97001.ISO).Attached){
Mount-DiskImage -ImagePath C:\testshare\97001.ISO
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To complement Abhijith's answer, and particularly to mention one bug I had to fight previously:

```
$imagePath = "path to your ISO-file"

$mount = Mount-DiskImage -ImagePath $imagePath -PassThru
$driveLetter =  ($mount | Get-Volume).DriveLetter
$drive = $driveLetter + ":\\"

# PowerShell bug workaround
# Forces PowerShell to update drive info for its providers
# Not doing so makes Test-Path fail on freshly mounted drives

Get-PSDrive > $null

$setupPath = $drive + "the path to your exe on the mounted drive"
$setupArgs = "your .exe args"

if (!(Test-Path $setupPath)) {
  # ... Something went wrong ...
} else {
    $process = Start-Process $setupPath -ArgumentList $setupArgs -Wait -PassThru
    # You can check $process.ExitCode here    
}
```